# SimpleXML how to get line number of a node?

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I'm using this in SimpleXML and PHP:

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $node) {
    echo $node->attributes('namespace')->id;
}
```

That prints the `id` attribute of all nodes (using a namespace).

But now I want to know the line number that `$node` is located in the XML file.

I need the line number, because I'm analyzing the XML file, and returning to the user information of possible issues to resolve them. So I need to say something like: "Here you have an error at line X". I'm sure that the XML file would be in a standard format that will have enough line breaks for this to be useful.

Comment: Why do you need the line number? An XML file could only have a single line, line breaks aren't mandatory. You can get the entry number using `foreach ($xml->children() as $entry => $node) {`

Comment: @MarkBaker I need the line number, because I'm analyzing the xml file, and returning to the user information of possible issues to resolve them. So I need to say something like: "Here you have an error at line X". I'm sure that the XML file would be in a standard format that will have enough lines. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: You're "surety" is misplaced.... there's no requirement for an XML file to have line breaks, it's not obliged to be prettified in any way, and indeed it often isn't prettified

Comment: @MarkBaker in this case is probably 99%... believe me...

Comment: Well, let me put it this way, PHP doesn't provide a way of reading line numbers through SimpleXML, nor through XMLReader, because they're reading the content of the file..... not arbitrary lines that may or may not exist.... if you need a line number from a file, then you'll need to do it the "old fashioned" way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible with DOM. `DOMNode` provides the function `getLineNo()`.

## DOM

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<foo>
  <bar/>
</foo>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('//bar[1]')->item(0)->getLineNo()
);
```

Output:

```
int(2)
```

## SimpleXML

SimpleXML is based on DOM, so you can convert `SimpleXMLElement` objects to `DOMElement` objects.

```
$element = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$node = dom_import_simplexml($element->bar);
var_dump($node->getLineNo());
```

And yes, most of the time if you have a problem with SimpleXML, the answer is to use DOM.

## XMLReader

XMLReader has the line numbers internally, but here is no direct method to access them. Again you will have to convert it into a `DOMNode`. It works because both use `libxml2`. This will read the node and all its descendants into memory, so be careful with it.

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open('data://text/xml;base64,'.base64_encode($xml));

while ($reader->read()) {
  if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name== 'bar') {
    var_dump($reader->expand()->getLineNo());
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like `XMLReader::expand::getLineNo` is capped at 65535.

Comment: Here is an option LIBXML_PARSEHUGE that can be used in the `open()` options argument. It changes the behavior of libxml.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but `LIBXML_PARSEHUGE` doesn't fix this problem.